# How to return some float values with zip() in Python function? TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, return

I wrote a simple function that wants to return more than 1 float values at the same time

```
def test_zip_float():
    return zip(1.234, 3.456)

print(test_zip_float())
```

It results in:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

I can rewrite it as:

```
def test_zip_float():
    return {"val1": 1.234, "val2": 3.456}

print(test_zip_float())
```

but it looks clumsy.

What is the best way to return multiple float values in a function?

Comment: `return (1.234, 3.456)`? `zip` takes two iterables and combines them into tuples element-wise until the length of the shortest iterable.

Comment: `zip([1.234, 3.456])`? I'm not really sure what do you expect to get. Why `zip` them instead of using a `list` in the first place?

Comment: *return 1.234, 3.456* will return multiple values (two in this case) as a tuple. Unclear why *zip()* is in play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without zip as well. It will return a tuple of float values:

```
def test_zip_float():
    return 1.234, 3.456

print(test_zip_float())

#(1.234, 3.456)
```

Comment: seems I read an incorrect tutorial. Thanks. Simple is the best.